# Cannot getname() newly added google sheet using changeType INSERT_GRID trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Looking to get the name of the newly added sheet (manually added) using an installable trigger. 
ChangeType with INSERT_GRID worked fine for me (tested by outputting some random value when sheet gets added) but when I try getting the name of the newly added sheet, it instead gives me the value of the FIRST sheet's name in the document.

Any alternatives? Have heard that this might be a previous bug in App Script.

```
function log(e)
{
if (e.changeType === "INSERT_GRID") {  
     var news = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName(); //fails to get correct value
     e.source.getSheetByName("Client").getRange(1, 1).setValue(news);
}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to detect the sheet name of added sheet using the OnChange event trigger.
- In your current issue, you cannot retrieve the sheet name of added sheet. When this is the bug or specification, you want to know about the alternatives for achieving your goal.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the event object of OnChange event trigger has not information about the added sheet. By this, when your script is used, the sheet name of the 1st tab is retrieved. I'm not sure whether this is the bug or the current specification.

So in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following workaround. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. At first, the initial sheet names are saved to PropertiesService.
2. When the sheet is added, the aded sheet is retrieved by comparing the current sheets and initial sheets retrieved from the PropertiesService.

#### Sample script:

In order to use this script, please close the Google Spreadsheet and open it again. By this, `onOpen` is run and the initial sheet names are saved to the PropertiesService. Then, when the sheet is added, the added sheet is retrieved and the sheet name of the added sheet is put to the cell.

```
function saveCurrentSheets(prop, spreadsheet) {
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets().reduce((o, s) => Object.assign(o, {[s.getSheetName()]: true}), {});
  prop.setProperty("sheets", JSON.stringify(sheets));
}

function onOpen(e) {
  saveCurrentSheets(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(), e.source);
}

function log(e) {
  if (e.changeType === "INSERT_GRID") {
    const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    const oldSheets = prop.getProperty("sheets");
    if (!oldSheets) {
      saveCurrentSheets(prop, e.source);
      return;
    }
    const oldSheetsObj = JSON.parse(prop.getProperty("sheets"));
    const addedSheet = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => !oldSheetsObj[s.getSheetName()])[0];
    const news = addedSheet.getSheetName();
    e.source.getSheetByName("Client").getRange(1, 1).setValue(news);
    saveCurrentSheets(prop, e.source);
  } else if (e.changeType === "REMOVE_GRID") {
    saveCurrentSheets(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(), e.source);
  }
}
```

- In this script, please install the OnChange event trigger to the function of `log`.
- In this script, when the existing sheet is deleted, the values of PropertiesService are updated by the current sheet names.

#### Note:

- When there are a lot of sheets in the Google Spreadsheet, I think that the initial sheet names are required to be a file instead of the PropertiesService, because of "Properties value size is 9kB / val." and "Properties total storage is 500kB / property store.". Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Event object of OnChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)
- [Class Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties)
- [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Answer (score 1):

That's the normal behavior. It always returns e.source.getSheets()[0]; Which is the same thing if you get the active sheet when you openById();