# How to change a formula automaticly when a new sheet is added (Add the sheet in formula)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want that my formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E206,Test!$C$2:$P$48,5,False),IFERROR(vlookup(E206,New!$C$2:$E$48,3,False),"-"))
```

to automatically update when I add a new sheet, so that I don't have to extend the formula by myself. It could happen that there will be 10 sheets added.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the formula to reference only a specific new sheet automatically when it gets created created, right? or additional new sheets will also be referenced?

Comment: There is no built-in trigger on Google app Script for when a new sheet is added to a spreadsheet. You could maybe create a time-driven trigger that will count the current number of sheets in the spreadsheet. you can archive that value in the scriptProperties and if the value saved differs in future calls, then you can make the script refresh your formula.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot getname() newly added google sheet using changeType INSERT\_GRID trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978427/cannot-getname-newly-added-google-sheet-using-changetype-insert-grid-trigger)

Comment: Thanks Tedinoz, THis will help me a bit with my script but will not solve the problem.

Comment: No there could be multiple new sheets which i dont know today.

Comment: @Askingfordummies when you mention that you want to "add the sheet in formula", what would be the expected new formula? Could you provide an example? I believe this is achievable but would need an example to understand your expected result.